# Logstash: metrics plugin not showing any outpout

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, metrics

Ηere is the start of my filter

```
filter {
if "paloalto" in [tags] {

metrics {
  meter => "events_paloalto"
  flush_interval => 60
  add_tag => "metric_paloalto"
}

...
```

And here is section of my `output`

```
if "metric_paloalto" in [tags] and "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "raw_metrics-%{+YYYY.MM.dd.HH.mm}"
    }

  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I am not getting anything on my `stdout` nor or my `elasticsearch` instance;

Any ideas?

Comment: if you move the `stdout` outside of the if-statement, do you see anything? Also, what is your `input {}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the following:

`metrics` actually creates a new event;

My `metrics` declaration was within an

```
if {} else drop {}
```

statement and the new (metric) event was dropped since it did not comply with the if check;

I moved it outside the `if` scope.